# How to realize strcmp function of string.h in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I tried to realize the `strcmp` function that is inside "string.h" library in C.
This is what I did:

```
int myStrCmp(char str1[], int len1, char str2[], int len2)
{
    int i = 0;
    int stop = 0;
    int cmp = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len1 && !stop; i++)
    {
        if (str1[i] == str2[i])
        {
            cmp = 0;
        }
        else if (str1[i] > str2[i]) 
        {
            cmp = -1; // gives 1 if string 1 will be appear first in dictionary.
            stop = 1; // stops the loop.
        }
        else
        {
            cmp = 1;  
            stop = 1;
        }
    }
    return cmp;
}
```

Everything is fine, but some cases of inputs for strings aren't working. As an example:

```
str1 = "ab";
str2 = "abcd";
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: This isn't what the parameters to the real `strcmp` look like - it takes two null-terminated strings without lengths.

Comment: Hmm `len2` is not used.  What is it for?

Comment: That is the problem with the len2

Comment: Post how `myStrCmp()` is called.  It is unclear if `len, len2` are the character array lengths or a limit on comparing less than the full string.

Comment: Note: when `strcmp()` compares the elements of a string, it compares them as `unsigned char`, even if `char` is _signed_.  `str1[i] > str2[i]` --> `(unsigned char) str1[i] > (unsigned char) str2[i]`

Comment: The signature for the C library `strcmp()` is `int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);`  If you want to replicate that behavior, then `len1, len2` are not needed.  Is your goal something different?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `len1` and `len2` are the length of `str1` and `str2` respectively.

You are not using `len2` in your code, which is causing logical errors, and could cause a crash (segmentation fault).

Following your code, a solution could be:

```
int myStrCmp(char str1[], int len1, char str2[], int len2)
{
    int i = 0;
    int stop = 0;
    int cmp = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len1 && i < len2 && !stop; i++)
    {
        if (str1[i] > str2[i]) 
        {
            cmp = -1; // gives 1 if string 1 will be appear first in dictionary.
            stop = 1; // stops the loop.
        }
        else if (str1[i] < str[i]
        {
            cmp = 1;  
            stop = 1;
        }
    }

    if (!stop && len1 != len2)
    {
        if (str[i] == '\0')
        {
            cmp = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            cmp = 1;
        }
    }

    return cmp;
}
```

Then, even this code works, it has a very poor style (and poor performance). I invite you to have a look at the Apple implementation of the strcmp function:

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    for ( ; *s1 == *s2; s1++, s2++)
        if (*s1 == '\0')
            return 0;
    return ((*(unsigned char *)s1 < *(unsigned char *)s2) ? -1 : +1);
}
```

https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-262/ppc/gen/strcmp.c

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not how `strcmp` works, and these are not the values it returns. Although most implementations will give you -1, 0 and 1, the [ISO standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says this:

> The strcmp function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or less than zero, accordingly as the string pointed to by s1 is greater than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by s2

This means it need not be -1, 0 and 1 always. You can expect any integer. This makes the implementation simple also.

```
int mystrcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    int diff;

    while(1)
    {
        diff = *s1 - *s2;

        if(*s1 == '\0' || *s2 == '\0')
        {
            break;
        }

        s1 ++;
        s2 ++;
    }

    return diff;
}
```